# How to align the top edge of each item to the top edge of each section in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report. In that I need to reduce much more space in detail section. how to do that?

I tried suppress method.but again it showing same problem. how to solve this ?

Here is my crstal report design and output samples.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IMdC.jpg)

output samples:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pi7k.jpg)

can any one suggest me how to eliminate space in the report while designing.

Comment: Actually couldnt understand where are you trying to reduce the space

Answer (score 0):

Ideally would need more details on what text you are trying to reduce.
Have you ensured there is no white space in the data that you are getting in the objects ?
Also do check the following settings to get the desired o/p
keep together, suppress blank section, relative position.